# How can I pass a system plugin in my launch file?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

How can I pass a system plugin in my launch file?

```
-s libgazebo_ros_api_plugin.so

<launch>

  <!-- roslaunch arguments -->
  <arg name="debug" default="false"/>
  <arg name="gui" default="true"/>  


  <!-- We resume the logic in empty_world.launch, changing only the name of the world to be launched -->
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(find rrbot_gazebo)/worlds/MyWorldfile.world" />
    <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)" />
    <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)" />
    <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
  </include>



  <!--node pkg="turtlebot_teleop" type="turtlebot_teleop_key" name="turtlebot_teleop_keyboard"  output="screen">
    <remap from="turtlebot_teleop_keyboard/cmd_vel" to="cmd_vel"/>
  </node-->

</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4981/how-can-i-pass-a-system-plugin-in-my-launch-file?/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/449/rnunziata/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 107 on 2013-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

ROS can't directly run gazebo because gazebo is a stand alone package. The gazebo_ros package works around this limitation by wrapping the gazebo executable inside a shell script. Only a few command line arguments are exposed if you use the `empty_world.launch` file.

You can pass in your own command line arguments using:

```
<node name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="gazebo" respawn="false" output="screen"
        args="-s <put_your_system_plugin_here.so>" />
```

To completely replace your example, you'd need:

```
<param name="/use_sim_time" value="true" />
<node name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="debug" respawn="false" output="screen" args="-u $(find rrbot_gazebo)/worlds/MyWorldfile.world"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/449/rnunziata/) on 2013-11-14**:
I think you are saying I can use  args="-u $(find rrbot_gazebo)/worlds/MyWorldfile.world -s <plugin.so>"

**Comment by [rnunziata](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/449/rnunziata/) on 2013-11-14**:
Are you saying I can pass